# Error when running Unity Project (Vuforia) as a library in Android Studio

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

Im trying to run Unity Project using Vuforia as a library in Android studio. I have added a button that will go to the UnityPlayerActivity. The apps running just fine but after i clicked the button. Only the unity logo appeared and the screen goes black.

This is from the logcat

2019-10-11 03:02:54.469 4448-4481/com.example.myapplication E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source:72)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:395)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
        at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:32)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-PaLDsjUgOPrhAiCRyAOD0w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-PaLDsjUgOPrhAiCRyAOD0w==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myapplication-
2019-10-11 03:02:54.520 4448-4488/com.example.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-10-11 03:02:54.526 4448-4481/com.example.myapplication E/Unity: Vuforia Engine cannot be started before it is initialized.
     Please disable Delayed Initializationin the Vuforia configuration or initialize Vuforia manually with the VuforiaRuntime-class.
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, String, Object)
    UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
    UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
    UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
    Vuforia.VuforiaARController:Start()
    System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke(Object, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo)
    System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke(Object, Object[])
    System.Delegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
    System.MulticastDelegate:DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[])
    System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke(Object[])
    Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])
    Vuforia.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling(Action)
    Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:Start()

Comment: There is some and possible solution on this error in the [vuforia forum](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/androidjavaexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-comvuforiavuforiaunityplayervuforiainitializer-error). Did you check them out?

Comment: @aalmigthy thank you ! I will check them out and let you know if i fixed it.

Comment: @aalmigthy I have added "implementation(name: 'VuforiaWrapper', ext:'aar')" to the build.gradle . Problem solved. Thanks !